Ryanair seating policy: will two passengers be seated apart if you don't pay for a seat?
As an example, Alaska Airlines in the US won't allocate you a seat till the last second if you fly in the cheapest class, however they (generally) will always try to seat people together if they're traveling on the same reservation.
I have a ticket with Ryanair from Pisa to Prague for two adults. If I don't pay for a seat, is Ryanair likely to seat us apart? I've never flown with them before with another person so don't have personal experience.

My experience with low-budget airlines, not including Ryanair, is that they won't do it on purpose but they will distribute those who don't book specific seats as to their liking. I've had flights with my wife through Jet2 (IIRC) where we weren't sat together, and in Australia plenty of flights where they've sat my family apart (while ensuring that an adult is sat with kids, but only when we've told them).

Note that the middles are the least desirable seats and thus typically the last to go.  If you're getting the last seats you should expect them to be mostly middles.  And only a 3-4-3 or 2-5-2 configuration permits adjacent middles.  The only 3-4-3 bird I've known is the 747 which is basically gone by now, I'm not aware of what operates a 2-5-2.  I've never heard of a 2-4-2 or a 2-3-2 but I wouldn't swear no bird uses them.

@LorenPechtel yes, if people pay for aisle/window seats I obviously wouldn't expect to sit together. But normally I do expect the airlines algorithm to try and give me adjacent seats if possible.

@LorenPechtel: Ryanair only flies 737s which are invariably 3-3.  (But for reference, the A380 typically uses 3-4-3 in Economy; the A330 and A340 are 2-4-2, and the 767 is 2-3-2.)


We recommend that you reserve your seat when booking or when checking in to guarantee a seat beside your travel companions. If you choose not to reserve a seat, then a seat will be randomly allocated to you free of charge when checking in, but it is unlikely it will be beside your travel companions.

(from Ryanair Seat Policy)
Ryanair has also had to deny that they deliberately separate such seats, so your chances are at most as good as random.
In general, Ryanair is a low-cost airline whose business model heavily relies on cheap base prices and a large amount of additional paid conveniences, of which seat selection is one, so I wouldn't expect to get it for free - certainly not as a matter of course.

RyanAir is the only low-cost airline in Europe I know of that separates customers like this. EasyJet, which has similar prices and routes, does not.

Customers can purchase [...] seat from just €2 [...]. Adults travelling with children are required to purchase one allocated seat (priced just €4) [...] - while I have no 1st-hand experience with them, whenever I read anything about Ryanair, they somehow tend to end up appearing a bit scummy. Yeah, for completeness: the sentence ends with up to four children on the same booking will be given free allocated seats, which is nice, but 2 and 4 still remain being different numbers.

@tevemadar They're not "a bit". They're very serious about "not a peanut for free".

If there are 50 free seats and they randomly assign seats to you and to your travelling companion, simple math says it's highly unlikely you'll be sitting together, even leaving out the probable middle seat excess.  Consider also that most airlines have seats in groups of three, but usually people travel in twos, leaving one empty.

@Therac It still surprises me that Ryanair isn't (yet) charging people for the privilege of breathing while in their planes.

@Tonny shhhhh... don't give them any ideas!

Ryanair didn't "deny that they deliberately separate such seats [to make money]" (like this answer and the linked headline claims), they merely said that seats are randomly allocated and there are less seats available for random allocation. But pure random allocation would practically guarantee that you wouldn't sit next to your travel companions. Ryanair may very well have specifically chosen to use pure random allocation because that would separate people, so they'd rather pay for seats, so Ryanair would make more money. There's nothing about what they said which refutes that.

@NotThatGuy I understood "deliberately separate" as "ensure you don't randomly get assigned a seat anywhere near the person you're traveling with". They do admit it's random, but are denying that it's even worse than that.

@MaciejStachowski there wouldn’t be a point of implementing something specifically to separate people, since random assignment pretty much guarantees it most of the time, and still gives them plausible deniability. Trying to seat people together would actually require more implementation effort than random assignment. They are basically admitting that they don’t make this effort.

@JackAidley: I flew with EasyJet two weeks ago, and I had to pay extra to ensure that I was seated with my travelling companion. Are you saying that EasyJet doesn't deliberately separate people if they don't pay the extra charge?

@TonyK I'm saying that if you fly with EasyJet and don't pay with seats you will most likely still be seated next to your companions.

@DidierL the point would be to make sure that you pay the surcharge next time :) Although I doubt Ryanair lies on that one, people are just bad with statistics. That said, it wouldn't take much effort to just assign sequential seat numbers when you buy multiple tickets, most transport providers do that - when I buy multiple train tickets here, for instance, the seats are usually next to each other or at least close by.

@DidierL Fill empty seats in the order which people purchased tickets.  does a pretty good job at sticking people next to each other... while requiring less effort than random selection (Randomly generating numbers is hard. It is basically impossible to prove that something is "truly random".

Unlike other airlines, when flying with RyanAir assume you'll be sitting apart from the person you fly with unless you pay for seats. RyanAir deny they deliberately separate people but they are clearly lying about this.
Since there's been a lot of discussion about the side point of whether RyanAir's policy of separating people on their flights can count as "deliberate". There is a technical sense in which you could argue you that it is not - what they seem to be doing is simply allocating each customer a seat at random rather than what (almost?) every other airline does and trying to place customers who booked together next to each other when possible whilst doing this allocation. However, in my opinion, the choice of how to assign seats is clearly a deliberate act and thus RyanAir's decision to go against that counts as them deliberately separating people.
Back in 2018, a CAA survey found that RyanAir were already separating passengers over twice as often (35% of passengers) as was normal for other airlines. However, although I can't prove it, I am quite certain that they changed their method of seating after this time to make it much worse. Certainly it was after this time that everyone I know who flew RyanAir found themselves being separated, and when I experienced the same.
Personally, for us, this was the point that we decided RyanAir had gone too far and decided to never fly with them again. It's one thing to charge for actual extras that better airlines include for free. It is quite another to deliberately make the experience worse unless you pay them.

Flying with easyJet, when I still did that, never used Ryanair, I noticed that most seats reserved were aisle and window seats, leaving only single seats left for those not selecting a seat early on. So maybe Ryanair does not have to do it on purpose, the people paying for their seats arrange it for them.

@Willeke I've never been separated flying with EasyJet, everyone I know has always been separated when flying with RyanAir. Besides with RyanAir the people sitting next to me and my wife had also been separated.

"RyanAir deny they deliberately separate people but they are clearly lying about this." Er, how is this "clear"? Are you saying it's been statistically proven that co-travelers end up together less frequently than would occur in random seating arrangements? Any links to back it up?

@user541686 no, even random chance alone is sufficient to make it unlikely. But other airlines try to seat people together if possible, even when flying on cheapest fare.

@JonathanReez: Yeah that's what I would've expected too. That's not deliberate separation, as accused here.

@user541686: It is deliberate separation, because they deliberately choose to use an algorithm that separates people; unlike other airlines and unlike they used to do themselves.

I think this falls into the "other airlines do it for free, ryanair wants you to pay for it" category, since they aren't deliberately separating people, just letting entropy do its work, opposite to other airlines that actively keep people together. But that's just my opinion, and you're welcome to think differently about it ;)

Flagged as NAN. This is just personal experience and not factual.

While a personal experience, it does answer the question. Expect to be separated unless you pay for the seat.

This seems like a baseless (and borderline libellous) accusation. Ryanair have gone out of their way in both their literature and in the press to deny that they intentionally separate passengers who book together but don't pre-book their seating.

@JackAidley: You do realize that booking people together is what requires extra work, right? Both for the algorithm (more computation, and BTW this smells NP-hard) and sometimes for the humans involved. Whereas literally ignoring the bookings and merely assigning seats to people independently is what requires no extra work. They used to do extra work for you. Now they don't. That's not "deliberately separating" you, it's "deliberately refusing to go out of their way to do more work for you than for other passengers". Wish  could give a -100 for the blatantly baseless accusation of lying.

@user541686 1) The trivially simple algorithm of putting people together when possible (like every other airline does, don't pretend this is hard) works fine and they is exactly zero need for human involvement. 2) They themselves already used this algorithm and then chose to change, actually requiring deliberate work on their part. 3) No-one, literally no-one, is asking for "extra work than for other passengers".

@JackAidley: (1a) The human involvement comes in when some family complains that they didn't get seated together like all the other families. Customer service then has to deal with that, flights might get delayed, etc... i.e. all extra costs. (1b/2/3) Even as far as the algorithms go, the algorithm is clearly more expensive when accounting for family seating. This isn't something I'm "pretending" to be true (yet another slanderous accusation from you; will you stop?); this is a simple fact. Just because you have 0 clue what their algorithm used to cost, that doesn't mean it came for free.

@user541686 There is no guarantee of sitting together on other airlines. You are being ridiculous. I will not reply further.

I've just had 4 flight segments on KLM (i.e. legacy carrier, and not a low cost airline). 2 people on the booking, separated on 3 of the 4 segments. Especially noticeable on the first segment, which had many empty seats, including entire empty rows. But still separated.

They do seat you deliberately apart to try to sell you seats. They allocate seats from back and front of the airplane, not by the sequence like other airlines. So every other seat goes from the front and usually mid seat and the next from the back.
However, there is an easy to trick to sit together in premium seats on Ryanair flights for free.

Hello Traveller and welcome to TravelStackExchange.
Can you post the tips you linked in your message itself as well? That way if the website behind your URL ever goes offline, your answer is still usefull.
